# Is there an easy way to search all the transactions?

Tags: transactions, privacy, blockchain

Is than an easy way to search the list of all bitcoin transactions? For example to find all the bitcoins sent to or from an address?

Comment: http://blockchain.info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [BlockExplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/), it can search by block, public address, and a few other ways. It also has some cool analysis and statistics abilities.

Comment: Just remember that a person can have any number of Bitcoin accounts. So if you enter their account and it says their balance is 30 Bitcoins, that means they have at least that many. It can accurately report all Bitcoins transferred to or from a particular address.

Answer (score 0):

`http://blockexplorer.com/address/<insert address here>`

will give you a list of all transactions to/from that address. [Here is an example](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1127YKBDm8d2ZEvFwGz3e6NaWUr4LNQSBE).